# Getting the index of all repeating element of a column, given a specified order

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I have a dataframe such as:

```
                Price   Ticket
Id                            
505          86.5000  110152           
258          86.5000  110152           
760          86.5000  110152           
263          79.6500  110413           
559          79.6500  110413           
586          79.6500  110413           
111          52.0000  110465           
476          52.0000  110465           
431          26.5500  110564           
367          75.2500  110813           
171          33.5000  111240
```

I want to fill a dictionnary with :
- keys :we enumerate the number of keys in the dict (from 1 to 3 in this case)
- values: 'Id' (aka. the index).

For this example I would get something like: {'1': ['505', '258', '260'], '2':['263', '559', '586'], '3':['111','476']}

The dataframe is already sorted by the 'Ticket' column, and I want it to stay that way. Why?
I wanna be able to use the dictionnary and dataframe (still ordered by 'Ticket') to find out if any ID in the dict is associated with a sequence of name elsewhere in the dataframe.

I've written the code below, but I get the following Error: 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'.

```
def same_price(df=df):
    df= df.sort_values(by='Ticket')
    nucleus= dict()
    k=0
    while df.shape[0]>=2:
        if df.Price.iloc[0]==df.Price.iloc[1]:
            value= df.Price.iloc[0]
            n=0
            nucleus[k]= []
            while df.Price.iloc[n]==value:
                nucleus[k].append(df.index[n])
                n+=1
                if n>df.shape[0]:
                    df.drop(nucleus[k], axis=0, inplace=True)
                    break 
            else:
                df.drop(nucleus[k], axis=0, inplace=True)
                k+=1       
        else:
            if df.shape[0]>=3: 
                df.drop(df.index[0], axis=0, inplace=True)
            else:
                break
    return(nucleus)
```

Given the Error, I believe that Im calling the first element of an empty list. But I cant fix it.   I would like to keep that function (and upgrade it) plz guys :)

Comment: @ALollz Thank you :) I updated my question also with ur comment

Answer (score 4):

You can try filtering with `series.duplicated()` and `groupby+agg`

```
(df[df['Price'].duplicated(keep=False)].reset_index()
.groupby('Price',sort=False)['Id'].agg(list).to_dict())

#{86.5: [505, 258, 760], 79.65: [263, 559, 586], 52.0: [111, 476]}
```

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. My question wasnt clear, I edited it

Comment: @Jeremy its bad practice to edit the question once it has been answered. However , You can try `d = (df[df['Price'].duplicated(keep=False)].reset_index()
 .assign(Price=lambda x:x['Price'].factorize()[0]+1).groupby('Price')['Id'].agg(list).to_dict())`